# How to test the andrioid app with out rooting the device

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am planning to develop and test the android app on a device instead of emulators.

Can i test the app with out rooting the device. Please share your thoughts.

Thanks.

Comment: What makes you think the device needs to be rooted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes (and good choice by the way - those things are mind numbingly slow), you simply allow debugging (Developer Options) in the phone's settings (specific to device, sometimes hidden), connect with a USB cable, write the app, start the app, choose to run on said device.

The emulators are good for testing the UI on device types you don't have access to, like a tab for example, that may require additional resources like layouts and images. Or, of course, if you don't have any devices.

Comment: so, it doesn't need to be a rooted device ?

Comment: Not in my experience on about 5 different devices. Rooting isn't very common and extremely frowned upon by service providers, so it wouldn't be a great choice to make that a req.

Comment: @kesava So long as you enable Developer Options on your device, you can use your device as a replacement for the emulator. No root required.